# is there a way to store data that was printed to screen as a string?

Tags: java, string

Is there any way i can take what was printed to the screen in java and store it as a String?

something like

```
String name = last printed statement;
```

Comment: Print screen -> OCR-program -> toString()? Please add some details to have better answers. Some last System.out()? log.debug()?

Comment: Before printing to the "screen", store the string in an object. Boom, now you have it stored.